# Uploading Multiple files to Sharepoint 2013 via using the proxy API to validate the file upload process (using vti_bin/copy.asmx)

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I had search all over and can't find something that might really help.

We have local folders and each folder named by the client name and the same case for the document library in the SharePoint.

We need to have C# console that will be able to upload those files to the dedicated client folders in the SharePoint 2013 library but we need to go through   proxy API to validate the file upload process (using vti_bin/copy.asmx).

Upload frequency: Monthly / Weekly 
Upload volume:  1000 files per transaction / 2 to 3 mb per file (approx)

Any ideas?

Can this be done by powershell or we stick to C#?